# Disallow containers to access host's network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a simple docker-compose structure like this

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    image: myapp
  db:
    image: mydb
```

a bridge network is automatically created, which allows:

1. `app` and `db` to see each other
2. `app` and `db` to see the host's network
3. `app` and `db` to reach internet

How can I disallow point 2 while keeping the other two?

Does explicitly creating a bridge network make any difference?

Comment: the `FORWARD` chain of iptables on the host is probably the place to place a `-A FORWARD -s appIP -d HOSTNetwork/mask -j DROP` line...